# IPhone Playing sound over a phone call

Tags: ios, iphone, audio

I would like to play a sound file during a phone call so that the person at the other end of the line can hear it clearly.

I know it is possible to play sounds on the line but i can't figure out how to cut the microphone at the same time so the person at the other side of the line don't hear ambient noises.

Does someone knows how to do that? Or have any cue where I could look for information?

Comment: My question was not clear. If you take a look at an application named "Escape Pod", it does just what I want to do, playing a sound while a phone call take place. But if you mute the phone's microphone, the person at the other end don't ear the sound anymore. I would like to be able to mute the mic on my phone but not the playing sound so the other person continue earing it, like putting the line onhold. The only thing missing is how to cut off the mike without cutting the sound (or music)

Comment: I am also looking for the same functionality. How is this possible. can u give me some idea to implement this. Ambient noises is not an issue in my case.

Comment: I have chatted with the Escape Pod developer. The app was pulled for patent infringement. Which means there IS such an app out there that will play a sound over the phone. Now the challenge is to find it.

Answer (score 1):

I very much doubt it is possible.

A telephone is an emergency communication device. The inability to make, receive or even clearly hear a phone call could literally kill someone. Consequently, the iPhone API strongly protects the integrity of the phone before all other functions.

Even if you did figure out a way, I doubt Apple would let it through. (Think of the liability issues for them and you!) The iPhone isn't a very small laptop, its a phone with a computer attached and the phone comes first.

You should always consider that when starting a design.

Comment: Yeah, I doubt you can do it with the public API and if you build against the private, your bound to get punted out of the store in due time.

So what, you want to play farts sounds over my phone call?!?!