# Adding a background noise on an Android phone call

Tags: android, audio, call

From what I have figured out so far, it is not possible to mess with the audio streams outgoing and ingoing from the phone during a phone call using the API's.

Would it be possible to do if one manipulated the source code for the Android OS or is this an impossible complicated task?

Comment: Why? Trying to prank a friend?

Comment: It's not impossible to modify Android's source but it's not easy either.

Comment: While it's about iOS and not Android, the first answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2137068/62576) may provide some insight into why this isn't likely to succeed. (And if you're not trying to prank a friend, it's probably to make your wife/girlfriend think you're somewhere other than where you are. :-))

Comment: You cannot! Plain and simple! Audio streams in respect to in-call, listening music are mutually exclusive! If in call, Audio streams are re-directed to earpiece and mouthpiece. If not in call, audio streams are redirected to speaker (if headset plugged in, it gets redirected to headset). Cannot have it both ways as that's the proprietary nature of the baseband firmware handing the Audio in the System On Chip (SoC).