# How can you access the audio for transmission in live phone calls in android based device

Tags: android, audio, filter, stream, phone-call

I would like to access my voice (during a phone call) so that I can filter the unwanted noise. I've encountered apps that can record both sides of the call during a live session (no VOIP)

https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.androidpit.com/en/android/market/apps/app/com.soundmobilesystems.android.recorder/Personal-Call-Voice-Recorder&sa=U&ei=p1bIUYmuFKboiAKx34CoAQ&ved=0CBYQFjAF&client=internal-uds-cse&usg=AFQjCNE9HZmEc9hNokPMGIFl0VWJMQv3nw

using Voice_Call, Voice_Uplink or Voice_Downlink, they were able to access the in call audio stream, my problem is now, how can i send my (noise filtered) voice back into the call audio stream.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stream audio to a phone call Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268964/stream-audio-to-a-phone-call-android)

Comment: any guesses why, with the prevalence of malware on Android, this would be a really bad idea were it to be possible?

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked several times before (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544992/call-audio-stream-modification-in-android-4-0-ics?rq=1), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754712/adding-a-background-noise-on-an-android-phone-call?rq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268964/stream-audio-to-a-phone-call-android?rq=1)).

Nothing has changed in respect to this, so it's still not possible for Android apps to write into the uplink (or downlink) of a voice call, and probably won't be in the future.

When it comes to noise suppression for voice calls, most (if not all) OEMs have both uplink and downlink noise suppression on their phones which has been carefully tuned for each product in a controlled environment to meet all necessary acoustic requirements. Sometimes you can toggle or tweak these settings in the Settings menu or through the Phone application's UI.