# IPhone place voice call and play voice message through

Tags: ios, iphone, call, voice, carrier

Is there a way to place a standard call and when call is in progress to play some predefined voice?

For example, I want my app to automatically call someone at predefined time and then to play message I've recorded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, [you cannot interfere with a customer's phone call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137068/iphone-playing-sound-over-a-phone-call).  And Apple wouldn't approve this app for the app store if you submitted it.

Comment: I had my doubts about that too, but that became true!
Thanks!